# A sensible way to design a reactjs page components with a large parent data structure

Tags: reactjs

I've just started on reactjs and am trying to figure out the right way to design my components. I get the concept of components, props, states but struggling a bit with the right way to design for a hierarchy.

I have a page that's driven by a big object array. Say

```
objArr = {
  param1 : value1,
  param2: value2,
  dataArray: [
               { key: "keyvalue", a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" },
                ...
             ]
 }
```

The entire page builds off of this. The page builds a series of UI components corresponding to the dataArray.

Now each time some of the icons are clicked in the UI, I want some changes, and the icons correspond to a value on this dataArray. What's a good way to ensure the dataArray values are changed as the UI is acted on? and vice versa, the UI changes as values are changed on the dataArray.

I've read "make components as stateless as possible," fine - then how do I do this handling at the parent component level and have it flow down?

I don't need code examples. Just a few pointers of the way to architect my ReactJS code would be great, I will figure out the code.

Thank you

Comment: If your application state is sufficiently complex that these kinds of questions start coming up it might be worth your time to research Redux, or another application state library (flux, mobx, etc.). Besides that, it is just about passing your application state down through properties, but hopefully only the ones the child components will make use of.

Comment: What you would want to do is to breakup you components into smaller ones called "presentational components" and have container components holding all the logic (click handlers, state processing, etc) and pass only the needed information as props to those smaller presentational components as @erik-sn said. Dan Abramov, redux creator, has some videos in his [Redux tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-extracting-presentational-components-todo-todolist) with the same subject, that not only applies to redux apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is bind a method on the Parent component and pass it down to the child container like so:

```
// Our 'pages' that we want to be able to interact with
const ComponentWIthButtons = ({handleButtonClick, buttons}) => (
    <div>
        <p>Hey, click one of these</p>
        {buttons.map(button => (
            <div onClick={()=>handleButtonClick(button.name)}>
                {button.text}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
// The Parent we want to interact with
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            buttons: [
                {
                    name: 'a',
                    text: 'Awesome button'
                },
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    text: 'Beautiful button'
                },
                {
                    name: 'c',
                    text: 'Cool button'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    // This is what you want to do with the information passed
    handleButtonClick = (name) => {
        // this could be updating this components' state, which
        // would rerender the display component because we pass it
        // our buttons from our state object
        console.log(name)
    };

    render(){
        return <div>
            <h2>Below are some buttons!</h2>
            // If you don't use the syntax above, you will run into
            // errors trying to get a reference to this container through
            // `this`. You can do this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)
            // to get around that
            <ComponentWIthButtons handleButtonClick={this.handleButtonClick} buttons={this.state.buttons} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will need some time to get my head around this. I haven't used ES6 code in mine, so the initial const ComponentWithButtons declaration isn't familiar. Will return once I spend time on this concept.

Comment: `const ComponentWithButtons` is just a way to write a totally stateless component. It could easily be `class ComponentWithButtons extends React.Compont` and have all of the lifecycle hooks and normal syntax available and then you could access the passed props via `this.props.buttons` and `this.props.handleButtonClick`